# How to prepopulate Ionic 2 ion-input field from Firebase object observable

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire

We use the async pipe to output value of a af.database.object as shown below.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseObjectObservable} from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <h1>{{ (item | async)?.name }}</h1>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  item: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.item = af.database.object('/item');
  }
}
```

But I have been trying to do the same on an Ionic 2 Form field to prepopulate a form for edit (in the below code) but have been unsuccessful.

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.name" name="content" value="{{ (item | async)?.name }}" required></ion-input>
```

This previously worked for my Angular 2 website edit form. But it seems that when working with an ion-input field in Ionic 2, it does not work.

Comment: You have doubling binding it looks like.  1 on ngModel linking product.name and another 2 value on item.  Try removing the 2 way binding on ngModel.